# How do I format the XML that Savon outputs to the terminal?

Tags: xml, ruby-on-rails-3, soap, savon

How do I format the XML that Savon outputs to the (OSX) terminal?

I currently get everything mangled up in a single line, which is hard to read.

I want something like this, formatted on multiple lines:

```
DEBUG -- : <env:Envelope
DEBUG -- :     xmlns:blz="http://thomas-bayer.com/blz/"
DEBUG -- :     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
DEBUG -- :     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
DEBUG -- :     xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
DEBUG -- :   <env:Body>
DEBUG -- :     <blz:getBank>
DEBUG -- :       <blz:blz>70070010</blz:blz>
DEBUG -- :     </blz:getBank>
DEBUG -- :   </env:Body>
DEBUG -- : </env:Envelope>
```

I have googled, searched here on SO, read the docs and github issues for Savon etc. to no avail.

Does anyone know?
@rubiii ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed the same thing and didn't get what I wanted from the older answer.

Savon's `SOAP::Response` has [a method called doc](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/savon/0.9.7/Savon/SOAP/Response#doc-instance_method) that returns `Nokogiri::XML::Document`. This gave me nicely formatted XML whether I wrote it to a file or displayed it in console using `puts`.

```
client = Savon.client(wsdl: "http://service.example.com?wsdl")
response = client.call(:my_operation)
puts response.doc
```

Comment: How did you get Savon to output it by default, instead of the mangled up one? Any code?

Comment: I feel like I might be missing something, but I added sample code. This formatted nicely in my Rails console on OSX. Does this not work for you?

Comment: Ah, my project is still on a way old Savon version, so the Savon:Module doesn't have the client method. I have moved to other projects, so I will assume your answer works, and accept it as the correct answer.

Comment: Even in the docs for Savon v1 I see Savon.client - check the getting started section here: http://savonrb.com/version1/getting-started.html ... are you even earlier than v1?

Comment: heh, yeah, it was an old project. I was on 0.9.7 :p The question was from 2012, remember.

Answer (score 0):

Transform the response into a Nokogiri::XML object:

puts Nokogiri::XML(response[:foo][:bar])